# Compressing directories on server without ssh

Tags: apache-2.2, tar, compression

Is there a way to compress directories on a server without ssh access? We are transferring many domains and there is no ssh available on the current server. We would like to secure copy the directories over after compressed using tar or zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use any other method you have of running commands on the server to do the compression -- exec in a PHP script you upload, upload a shell script, telnet, use a known vulnerability in an installed web application on one of the sites... the possibilities are endless.

I'd just ask the hosting company to provide SSH access; if your hosting plan doesn't include SSH access, well, that's a bit of a planning fail (as it were).

Answer (score 1):

If you have php in the server, use a php shell (or python or ruby or whatever). For example http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/ but please you should read the documentation for security reasons.

And yes, like womble tells you, ask to your provider for a ssh access or change to other better company.

Comment: better company is always the ideal but sometimes you are in a place where you need to move existing files to new server.  Thanks for the input :)